# Multiple Entra Id Authentication through a dropdown in Azure AD B2C page

Tags: multi-tenant, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We have implemented Azure AD B2C for customer and user authentication for our application using custom policies. We have one Entra Id tenant for time being and is working as expected. We have a requirement for providing access to other Entra Id tenants as well. Here my requirement is to have a dropdown in the sign-in page where a user can select the country with single button and the login functionality should work. Can anyone please help me here?

I've made change to the extensions.xml where in I've added the new tenant id along with the secret and new button is coming on sign in. Upon clicking it's working as expected, however requirement is to have one single button on the sing in with a dropdown to navigate to particular tenant for authentication.